# My 'for' loop isn't updating my page counter properly. It's returning empty lists for certain results

Tags: python, json, list, rest, pagination

I'm trying to update *page_counter* for every URL that doesn't return an empty JSON response.

```
headers = {"Accept": "application/.v3+json", "Authorization": "Bearer {api_key}"}

api_url = "https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/%s/rate?page=%s"

page_counter = 1

     list =[
      {"state": "Ohio"},
      {"state": "Georgia"},
      {"state": "California"},
      {"state": "Texas"}
              ]

list_of_results = []

for i in list:
    state_name= i.get("state")
    url= api_url % (state_name, page_counter) #appends the key value of the state_name

print(url) returns >>>>> https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/Ohio/rate?page=1, https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/California/rate?page=1

    response = requests.get(url, headers=api_headers_somewhere)
    if response.json() != None:
        page_counter = page_counter + 1
    else:
        list_of_results.extend([item for item in response.json()])
```

Comment: Please fix the indention of the code, and is this the full code? where did you defined the `headers` var?

Comment: @omercotkd I fixed the indentation and I didn't really think the headers matters so I didn't include it in the snippet. Just updated it & yes this is the full code

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you didn't reset the `page_counter`, so for the next state you provided the API didn't have a page that high and as a result didn't return a JSON. You should use a *while* loop inside the *for* loop like so:

```
import requests
# changed the api_url to a function that returns an f string
def api_url(name, counter):
    return f"https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/{name}/rate?page={counter}"


page_counter = 1

list_ =[
{"state": "Ohio"},
{"state": "Georgia"},
{"state": "California"},
{"state": "Texas"}
        ]
list_of_results = []

for state in list_:
    state_name = state.get("state")

    pages = True

    while pages:
        url= api_url(state_name, page_counter)
        response = requests.get(url, headers="api_headers_somewhere")
        if response.json() != None:
            page_counter += 1

        else:
            pages = False
            page_counter = 1
            list_of_results.extend([item for item in response.json()])
```

A small note: `page_counter += 1` is the same as `page_counter = page_counter + 1`.

Don't forget to change the headers to the correct headers.

Comment: Thank you so much for breaking that down for me! Only think I'm confused about is why we are declaring `pages = True` ?

Comment: you need a condition for the `while` loop or it will not stop (endless loop) , and when there are no more pages to get data from you set this variable to `False`, and the condition is no longer `True` so the loop breaks, and you can continue to the next state.

Comment: That makes sense, however it appears that the loop is running indefinitely. I'm going to do some more digging so I can see what's going on. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem I hope you solve it, and that's a good night for me it's 3 AM lol

Comment: You're goated, thanks!